# Python multiprocessing pool code advances in code after join

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

So I have been trying to get the process to run this script using a pool of processes but when I run this it doesn't run my function and continues on to the print(result) and I get a NameError. This is probably a stupid mistake but I can't fix it

```
sim_list = [[100,10,10],[100,9,9]]
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(processes=2) as pool:
        result = pool.map(run, sim_list)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

print(result)

print("waiting")
time.sleep(60)
```

I sends three processes forward into the next lines of code

Comment: You can omit ```pool.close()``` and ```pool.join()```. Can you post the run function?

Comment: yes, but the processes would still continue on to the next lines of code. I only want it to run and return the function. The processes shouldnt be running code outside of the run funtion but they are